# WinForms deep nested controls resize kernel bug - Splitter Panels not scaling controls properly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-kernel

(initial guess at nested proved to be incorrect. Problem seems to be that SplitContainer panels do not scale their hosted controls properly.)

---

I have some forms that have tab controls that fail to resize properly at load time. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/953934 describes such a kernel bug in 2008. Hard to believe it hasn't been fixed. I think it went away for a while but I'm beginning to see problems again.

The controls are nested pretty deep. Midi Parent, child form, tab control, splitter control with two panels and controls. For the top down the first control with the problem is the tab control. It resizes when the form is resized after loading but the anchors are incorrect and part of the control is clipped.

The problem seems to be specific to 100% desktop font size - desktops with 100+ size work OK. I develop at 125% using VS 2013 v5 - the issue was present on v4 as well.

Anyone know of a work around short of the custom control as outlined in the KB article?

Something else going on I've missed?

---

Looking at it more closely the SplitContainer is the control not resizing/honoring the anchors.

---

I tried running this code after the tab was shown and it didn't work - looks about the same as using anchors. It seems that the TabControl is reporting an incorrect ClientSize

```
    SplitContainer1.Width = TabControl1.ClientSize.Width - 10
    SplitContainer1.Height = TabControl1.ClientSize.Height - TabControl1.ItemSize.Height - 10
```

---

Here is a complete form that shows the problem. On a 125% desktop it shows as in the IDE on a 100% desktop the controls on the tab are not positioned properly.

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frmChild
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.TabControl1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabControl()
    Me.TabPage1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
    Me.SplitContainer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.TabPage2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
    Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.TabControl1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.TabPage1.SuspendLayout()
    CType(Me.SplitContainer1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SplitContainer1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'TabControl1
    '
    Me.TabControl1.Anchor = CType((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.TabControl1.Controls.Add(Me.TabPage1)
    Me.TabControl1.Controls.Add(Me.TabPage2)
    Me.TabControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(82, 2)
    Me.TabControl1.Name = "TabControl1"
    Me.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Me.TabControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(466, 436)
    Me.TabControl1.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'TabPage1
    '
    Me.TabPage1.Controls.Add(Me.SplitContainer1)
    Me.TabPage1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 25)
    Me.TabPage1.Name = "TabPage1"
    Me.TabPage1.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
    Me.TabPage1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(458, 407)
    Me.TabPage1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.TabPage1.Text = "TabPage1"
    Me.TabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'SplitContainer1
    '
    Me.SplitContainer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.SplitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.SplitContainer1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
    Me.SplitContainer1.Name = "SplitContainer1"
    Me.SplitContainer1.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal
    '
    'SplitContainer1.Panel1
    '
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
    '
    'SplitContainer1.Panel2
    '
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.SplitContainer1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(452, 401)
    Me.SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 223
    Me.SplitContainer1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Anchor = CType((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(371, 146)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'TabPage2
    '
    Me.TabPage2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 25)
    Me.TabPage2.Name = "TabPage2"
    Me.TabPage2.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
    Me.TabPage2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(854, 450)
    Me.TabPage2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.TabPage2.Text = "TabPage2"
    Me.TabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.Anchor = CType((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 13)
    Me.TextBox1.Multiline = True
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(344, 177)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Button2
    '
    Me.Button2.Anchor = CType((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(371, 195)
    Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
    Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.Button2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Button2.Text = "Button2"
    Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'frmChild
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(120.0!, 120.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(548, 439)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TabControl1)
    Me.Name = "frmChild"
    Me.Text = "frmChild"
    Me.TabControl1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.TabPage1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.PerformLayout()
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(False)
    CType(Me.SplitContainer1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.SplitContainer1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
Friend WithEvents TabControl1 As System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
Friend WithEvents TabPage1 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
Friend WithEvents SplitContainer1 As System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents TabPage2 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
Friend WithEvents Button2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
End Class
```

Comment: `I develop at 125%`  That might be the issue.  Your nested controls don't sound that deep, to be honest, so without seeing any code, there is probably a layout issue with your development setup.

Comment: Bug is in the kernel (if the KB applies) so there isn't any code to show.  Org standard is 125%, the outlaws are the problem. :)

Comment: Is the SplitContainer inside a TabPage?  Then you probably don't want the TabControl's client size, but the TabPage's client size.

Comment: True - but testing shows the layout OK on 125% but wrong on 100%.

Comment: In form above - I compiled on a 100% desktop with no changes and the problem appeared. I changed the form's AutoScaleMode from DPI to Font and it shows OK on 100% but anchors are off at 125%. So scale mode is not a fix if I can't used mixed desktops. I have 30+ forms that work 99% at both resolutions - the ones with SplitContainer seem to be the problem children.

Comment: I tired KB suggested solution - didn't help. If I move the split container to the form (from a tab) it works properly at both resolutions.

Comment: I don't know what the form looks like, but it sounds like you should just Dock.Fill the SplitContainer control if it's the only control inside the TabPage.

Comment: No difference - docked vs. anchored. Problem is boiling down to a Splitcontainer contained within a tabcontrol. Either the height or width is being reported incorrectly to the splitercontrol so controls anchored to the panels edges are not in the proper positon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `SplitPanel` isn't anchoring its contents correctly, you could try putting the contents into another container that is less buggy.

Try putting a `TableLayoutPanel` inside the `SplitPanel`. Set the `TableLayoutPanel.Dock` property to `Fill`, and then `.Anchor` your controls inside that. (Don't use `.Dock` inside a `TableLayoutPanel`, it's a bit flaky).

The controls inside the `TableLayoutPanel` will have new properties called `.RowSpan` and `.ColumnSpan` which allow the controls to span multiple cells.

There is a little arrow in the top right of the `TableLayoutPanel` that will allow you to edit the rows and columns. I find the best is to make as many as possible fixed width/height and then use percentage for the rest. I don't use `Autosize` but you could try that.

Comment: This workaround worked to cover up the bug (IMO.) Evidently the authors of the TableLayoutPanel didn't share their work with the other control authors. Is this a know bug?

Comment: I think it is a case of the autosize code in each control interacting in unexpected ways. If each control gets a turn resizing itself, who knows if a control later in the order might mean a control earlier needs to change again. I think the `TableLayoutPanel` resizes its children while the `SplitPanel` children resize themselves (badly). I'm just guessing, though.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I've add one of the suggested containers (plus the simple Panel) to my forms and it corrected the problem for the most part. RichTextBox height still isn't being set properly. The position of the splitter is off as well but I'm not sure there would be a way to deal with that. Other wise things look good.

Comment: 3 years on and that bug still exists :( I seem to get it more with 2 split containers within a tabcontrol. I'd swap to WPF but it seems like its a ton of work. Ive tried getting the splitter distance to resize the panels for my DGV's on the shown event but it doesnt work - yet if i put my splitterdistance changes under a click event of a button and click on it once the form has fully done its work when loading, it works properly. Im sure this is something to do with the order in which the controls are drawn on the form and if it the splitcontainers were resized last, it would work

Comment: Especially the tip of not using .Dock on the first level nested controls inside a TableLayoutPanel helped me out.